# Hibernate Spring Webflow One to Many Duplicate Primary Key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-webflow

ive been working on this for a while and can't seem to figure it out except that at some point it was working as was intended. I have two objects, a User which can be associatted with multiple addresses. Saving a new user and address together works just fine, but when i try to add a new address to an existing User i get an error about duplicate primary keys for User table. I guess it has something to do with the configuration in hibernate trying both unidirectional and bidirectional.

Below are any relevant files. Thanks of your help!

User.java

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class Users implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5699491123012997265L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idusers;

    @NotBlank(groups = { PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class })
    @Size(min = 5, max = 15, groups = { PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class })
    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\w{5,}$", groups = { PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class })
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(groups = { PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class })
    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\S+$", groups = { PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class })
    @Size(min = 8, max = 15, groups = { FormValidationGroup.class })
    private String password;

    private boolean enabled = false;
    private String authority;

    @Size(max = 25, groups = { PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class })
    private String name;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 10, groups = { PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class })
    private String phoneNo;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "idaddresses")
    private Set<Addresses> addresses;

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(String username, String password, boolean enabled,
            String authority, String name, String phoneNo,
            Set<Addresses> addresses) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.authority = authority;
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
    public int getIdUsers() {
        return idusers;
    }

    public void setIdusers(int idusers) {
        this.idusers = idusers;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public String getAuthority() {
        return authority;
    }

    public void setAuthority(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getIdusers() {
        return idusers;
    }

    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }

    public Set<Addresses> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(Set<Addresses> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    public void addAddress(Addresses addresses) {
        if (this.addresses == null) {
            this.addresses = new HashSet<Addresses>();
        }
        addresses.setUsers(this);
        this.addresses.add(addresses);
    }

}
```

Addresses.java

```
@Entity
   @Table(name = "addresses")
   public class Addresses implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -1239830513656245466L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idaddresses;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 5, max = 45)
    private String street1;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 5, max = 45)
    private String street2;

    @Size(min = 0, max = 200)
    private String special;

    private String apt;
    private String city;
    private String state;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idusers")
    private Users users;

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    public Addresses() {

    }

    public Addresses(String street1, String street2, String special,
            String apt, String city, String state, Users users) {
        this.street1 = street1;
        this.street2 = street2;
        this.special = special;
        this.apt = apt;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.users = users;
    }

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
    public int getIdaddresses() {
        return idaddresses;
    }

    public void setIdaddresses(int idaddresses) {
        this.idaddresses = idaddresses;
    }

    public String getStreet1() {
        return street1;
    }

    public void setStreet1(String street1) {
        this.street1 = street1;
    }

    public String getStreet2() {
        return street2;
    }

    public void setStreet2(String street2) {
        this.street2 = street2;
    }

    public String getSpecial() {
        return special;
    }

    public void setSpecial(String special) {
        this.special = special;
    }

    public String getApt() {
        return apt;
    }

    public void setApt(String apt) {
        this.apt = apt;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public Users getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Users users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

Part of flow that calls method

```
<view-state id="newAddress" model="address">
        <transition on="addNewAddress" to="customerReady" />
        <on-exit>
            <evaluate expression="address.street1 = requestParameters.street1"></evaluate>
            <evaluate expression="address.street2 = requestParameters.street2"></evaluate>
            <evaluate expression="address.apt = requestParameters.apt"></evaluate>
            <evaluate expression="address.city = requestParameters.city"></evaluate>
            <evaluate expression="address.special = requestParameters.special"></evaluate>
            <evaluate expression="address.city = requestParameters.city"></evaluate>
            <evaluate expression="address.state = 'NY'"></evaluate>
            <evaluate expression="user.addAddress(address)"></evaluate>
            <evaluate expression="usersService.update(user)"></evaluate>
        </on-exit>
    </view-state>
```

userService.update(user) sends you to dao

```
public void update(Users users) {
        session().saveOrUpdate(users);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Can u post some code snippet of how u fetching Existing user object and    how u r associating new address object to existing user object

Comment: `<view-state id="confirmCustomer" model="address">                                                                                                               
  <on-entry>
   <evaluate result="flowScope.user" expression="usersService.getCustomerByPhone(requestParameters.phoneNo)"></evaluate>
   <evaluate result="viewScope.addresses" expression="addressesService.getAddressByUserId(user.idusers)"></evaluate>
  </on-entry>
  <transition on="useAddress" to="readyCustomer"></transition>
  <transition on="newAddress" to="newAddress"></transition>
 </view-state>`

Comment: Through your comment alone i might be able to fix my error. I think you are right to suggest it is how i am fetching the user object beause when it was working it was doing it in a different fashion. Will test some things out to see if i can get it working but any more insight would be great.  Thanks for replying!